# ValueError: Linkage 'Z' uses the same cluster more than once in Python scipy fcluster

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I'm getting `ValueError: Linkage 'Z' uses the same cluster more than once.` when trying to get flat clusters in Python with scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster. This error happens only sometimes, usually only with really big matrices ie 10000x10000.

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
Z = sch.linkage(d, method="ward")
# some computation here, returning n (usually between 5-30)
clusters = sch.fcluster(Z, t=n, criterion='maxclust')
```

Why does it happen? How can I avoid it? Unfortunately I couldn't find any useful info by googling...

**EDIT** Error occurs also when trying to get dendrogram. 
No such error appear if `method='average'` is used.

Answer (score 0):

It seems using [fastcluster](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fastcluster) instead of `scipy.cluster.hierarchy` solves the problem. In addition, `fastcluster` implementation is slightly faster than `scipy`.
For more details have a look at [the paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v053i09).

```
import fastcluster
Z = fastcluster.linkage(d, method="ward")
# some computation here, returning n (usually between 5-30)
clusters = fastcluster.fcluster(Z, t=n, criterion='maxclust')
```